# Export from a GIS database and automatically populate an external document

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, pdf

I'm using a standard database based on ESRI polygon shapefile with 30 fields. The database is diverse with records from text values to long integer and double numbers. The records from the database needs to be linked with an external document/smart pdf file or Word file.  The Word file/smart pdf is formatted in a manner that only some parts of the document needs to be completed.
For example, I need to complete/autocomplete a sentence or a table with records from ESRI polygon shapefile, such as : Name ..... , Streets ......, city ........

Is there a plug-in, tool or algorithm scheme in order to link records from a shapefile (in software such as ESRI ArcGIS or Quantum GIS) to particularly paragraphs from an external document?

Comment: Maybe [ArcGIS Maps for Office](https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-maps-for-office/overview), but I havent tried it so I dont know.

Comment: Shapefile does *not* use database technology.

Comment: What do you mean by "linked"?  Do you need to dynamically update an existing document?  Or just to be able to export a document?  You could use data driven pages to export a PDF of text, including the attribute data from your shapefile.